# protect cell.textLabel.text on scroll event of UITableView

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, uitableview

How can I protect Text of UITableViewCell, which gets changed on scrolling of the UITableView.

```
static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Cell";
CustomTableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
if(indexPath.row != [destinationList count])
{
    if (cell == nil) 
    {
        cell = [[CustomTableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
    }
    cell.customLable.text = @"MyCustomLabel";
else
{
    if (cell == nil) 
    {
        cell = [[CustomTableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
    }
    cell.textLabel.text = @"Static Text to be set";
    [cell.customLable removeFromSuperview];
}
```

**Problem:** Every time I scroll the UITableView, @"Static Text to be set" gets overwritten on @"MyCustomLabel".

How can I prevent this? I want all the cells of UITableView to retains their TextLabels through Table's LifeTime.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Two possible answers:

1. Generally it doesn't matter. Reusing the cell is how it's supposed to work and you should fully "reset" each cell each time. You shouldn't be storing state in the cell anyway
2. Create a new reuseIdentifier, one for the custom label and another for the static text

Comment: But, It changes my "MyCustomLabel" to "Static Text to be set" (Which  is text for another cell).

Comment: Yes, that's what's supposed to happen. It only happens when the cell is no longer visible. And you can stop it doing that by using a different reuse identifier for the static cell. As I say in my answer.

Comment: Nothing Changed, even after creating new reuseIdentifier.

Comment: ended up using "initWithStyle:reuseIdentifier:nil".

Answer (score 1):

They will all retain their UILabels property, because cells get reused which is why you use:

```
[tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
```

However UITableView uses lazy loading meaning it ONLY keeps in memory visible UITableViewCells, therefore when you scroll the now invisible cells get reused, and now the new visible cells have the same UILabel as the ones that you can no longer see. That means there is really just a handful of UITableViewCells getting reused every time.

This is why in the docs [UITableViewCell](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UITableViewCell_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/cl/UITableViewCell) in the discussion for the instance method prepareforReuse:

If a UITableViewCell object is reusable—that is, it has a reuse identifier—this method is invoked just before the object is returned from the UITableView method dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:. For performance reasons, you should only reset attributes of the cell that are not related to content, for example, alpha, editing, and selection state. **The table view's delegate in tableView:cellForRowAtIndexPath: should always reset all content when reusing a cell.** If the cell object does not have an associated reuse identifier, this method is not called. If you override this method, you must be sure to invoke the superclass implementation.

Answer (score 0):

You should make different identifiers for different cells.
Anyway, to store something in UITableView is a wrong approach, it just to display data, not to store.

Answer (score 0):

why do you remove the custom label? Just remove the text of the label.

```
if(indexPath.row != [destinationList count])
{
    /* ... */
    cell.textLabel.text = @"";
    cell.customLable.text = @"MyCustomLabel";
else
{
    /* ... */
    cell.textLabel.text = @"Static Text to be set";
    cell.customLable.text = @"";
}
```

and make sure that does labels are transparent.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Cell";
CustomTableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];

if (cell == nil) 
{
    cell = [[CustomTableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
}
cell.textLabel.text = nil;
cell.customLabel.text = nil; 
if(indexPath.row != [destinationList count])
{
    cell.customLable.text = @"MyCustomLabel";
}
else
{
   cell.textLabel.text = @"Static Text to be set";
}
```